# How to rewrite $2\cos(x_1)x_2+\cos(x_2)$ to $2(\cos(x_1))^2x_2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Hello is it possible to rewrite this trigonometric equation?

Example
$2\cos(x_1)x_2+\cos(x_2)$
$=$
$(\cos(x_1-x_2)+\cos(x_1+x_2))x_2$

Who can it bee simplified to
$2x_2(\cos(x_1))^2$

the whole equation is

$-(x_2^2+\sin(x_3))^2x_2+2\cos(x_1)x_2\cos(x_2)+\cos(x_1)\cos(x_3)x_1+\cos(x_1)\cos(x_3)u$

should bee rewritten to 
$-(x_2^2+\sin(x_3))^2x_2+2(\cos(x_1))^2x_2+\cos(x_1)\cos(x_3)x_1+\cos(x_1)\cos(x_3)u$

see link below for more information
https://mec560sbu.github.io/2016/11/22/Linearization/

Comment: Well $2 (cos x)^2 y = y \cos(2x) + y$. Please tell us more about what you are looking for so we can better help you.

Comment: who do you calculate it

Comment: How would I know you didn't know $\cos^2 x = \frac{1}{2} (\cos(2x)+1)$?

Comment: sorry for really bad asked  question

Comment: Okay, here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). I assume you already learnt [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), but $\cos x$ can be written as \$\cos x\$. Please start reading these links so that you can improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution to my problem pretty amazing with sine and cosine

$\cos(x_1)\cos(x_2)=\frac{1}{2}(\cos(x_1-x_2)+\cos(x_1+x_2))=\frac{1}{2}(\cos(2x_1)+1)=\frac{1}{2}(2(\cos(x_1))^2-1+1)=(\cos(x_1))^2$

Answer (score 0):

2b(cos a)(cos b) = 2b(cos a)$^2$
can be rewritten as
b = 0 or cos a = 0 or cos b = cos a.

Comment: sorry for bad asking question

Answer (score 0):

With $x_1=0$,

$$2\cos(x_1)x_2+\cos(x_2)=2x_2+\cos(x_2)$$
and

$$2(\cos(x_1))^2x_2=2x_2.$$

You conclude.